# How to stop expressjs server

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

I have deployed my express and nextjs based app on EC2, I am trying to stop server so I kill process few second later I notice it automatically starts Nginx and node with diffrent porcess ID, I haven't added forever or nodemon etc.. it's just simple express server right now. How can I stop that.

[image]

I have tried to kill process but still my server.js is running

[image]

here my full package.json

[image]

Comment: Try to stop nginx with this: systemctl stop nginx

Comment: @Eitank Nginx is stop but node is still opening automatically with new PID

Comment: might need more details, like package.json and all

Comment: @Eitank package.json is too long I am sharing scripts    "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "npm run-script build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "go": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }

Comment: @Eitank check question I have added full package.json file.

Comment: when you run your application do you just run `npm start`?

Comment: try to run `killall node`

Comment: @Eitank tried but this command not working'

Comment: try `kill -9 4532`

Comment: @Eitank see the middle image  I tried to kill node process but it starts with another pid automatically

Answer (score 0):

This was automatically spawn by it's parent process, I search out parent process after killing that this stop as well.